# Replace query string with regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a query string parameter looks like below:

```
Nr=AND(OR(abc:def),OR(ghi:jkl),OR(mno:pqr).....so on)
```

I wanted to replace this query string to get the values inside the OR condition delimited between colon.

any help will be appreciated.!!

Comment: This ain't valid JavaScript, or a RegEx. Are you missing any tags?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: this query string based on the search with form values getting appended to get the result from back-end.

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: expected output would be abc,ghi,mno in a separate array and def,jkl,pqr in a separate array.

Comment: `OR\(([^:]*):([^)]*)\)` this would capture the text inside OR function and stored it into two seperate groups.

Comment: @Maniram may i post it as answer.

Comment: @Avinash : yeah man...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below regex would capture the text inside OR function and stored it into two separate groups using `:` as delimiter,

```
OR\(([^:]*):([^)]*)\)
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hV5sW5)

**Explanation:**

- `OR\(` Matches literal `OR(`.
- `([^:]*)` NOt of `:` character zero or more times. Finally it stores the matched characters into group1.
- `:` A literal :
- `([^)]*)` Not of a literal `)` character zero or more times. Finally it stores the matched characters into group2.
- `\)` Matches a literal `)` character.

Comment: It is matching all the OR values perfectly..but the array value returs only the first OR value only...For Ex. AND(OR(abc:def),OR(ghi:jkl),OR(mno:pqr)...). Above regex return only the abc:def value only.

Comment: In the demo it matches both. I think, some modifications would be done on your code only. You can ask it as another question.

Comment: +1 for concise solution with explanation and working demo. :)